# How to force a Windows 10 phonegap application to run in fullscreen?

Tags: cordova, windows-10, fullscreen, phonegap-build, phonegap

I have a huge Phonegap application built using Phonegap Build (So I don't have access to the underlying native code).

Everything's fine for iOS and Android, but on Windows 10, the app starts in a non-maximized Window.

How could I force it to run in fullscreen, or at least in a maximized window and prevent resizing ?

I tried this plugin : https://github.com/filfat-Studios-AB/cordova-plugin-fullscreen

But it doesn't change anything as-is.

Any idea ?

Thanks

edit: the `fullscreen` preference is already set to `true` in my config.xml

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use any plugin for `fullscreen`.

Try to set preference in config.xml: `<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />`

For full docs read [Preferences PhoneGap](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/preferences/).

Comment: Ah, should have mentioned I already set this preference in plugin.xml ;)